# How to pass a super long argument in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line-arguments

I wrote a Python programme, that accepts an argument I pass to it. But when I pass a very very long argument, it automatically shortens my argument.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the argument?

Comment: the command and the terminal are both important, yet the question lacks both of those information. Sometimes it's due to the issue while printing in the program and not related to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the arguments in a text file, one per line. Then,

```
xargs python myprogram.py < argslist.txt
```

`xargs` reads in a list of tab, newline, or space-delimited arguments from standard in, and then feeds it to the utility to be executed after additional arguments on the command line.

So where here we have `xargs utility arg1 < extraArgs.txt`, `xargs` is going to execute `utility`, pass `arg1` as the first argument and then since we are redirecting the contents of `extraArgs.txt` to `xargs`' standard in stream, it will append the arguments after `arg1`.